# Do office celebrations make a company stronger and bring people closer, or does it just waste work hours?

Tags: human-resources, relationships, time-management

In our company, we celebrate birthdays and some Indian feasts. It helps to take a time-out, to reboot the brains and to improve relationships. My concern, however is that these celebrations are during work hours.  Is this a good use of time?

Comment: The higher-ups in your company have decided that it is, indeed, a good use of time. You yourself seem to be aware of the benefits. Is there a reason why you'd suppose that's not actually the case?

Comment: I think "what are the pros and cons" would be a more on-topic question as "is it a good use of time / a good idea?" is dependent on so many factors and largely opinion-based.

Comment: They do for some people, for others they don't, it's part of an overall strategy for teambuilding and intracompany networking, rather than a solution on it's own. There is a good reason behind having them during working hours, it allows everyone to participate who may have other obligations outside working hours.

Answer (score 3):

> Do office celebrations make a company stronger and bring people closer, or does it just waste work hours?

Yes.

In some offices, with some cultures, these celebrations allow people to mingle and bond, building stronger relationships with each other and with the company that facilitated the event.

In some offices, with some cultures, these celebrations are a forced contrivance. You're forced to go eat bad cake and celebrate some arbitrary achievement rather than getting real work done.

And in probably most offices, you have both at the same time, because people are *different*. Some people like the celebrations, and some think they are worthless.

Answer (score 2):

More effective and less expensive than most "team-building exercises". Relax and enjoy the break.

Answer (score 1):

It is good for the employees and the company, **up to a certain point**.

Parties and celebrations should be the 'exception' not the rule.

If there is such a celebration every single week, or on a very frequent basis, the magic of it could fade away, because there is often a protocol involved:

> It's Amanda's birthday today, we expect **everyone** to be in the meeting room at **13h00**, we serve the cake at **13h15**, and we sign the **Happy Birthay song at 13h18**. You have to **wait** until everyone gets his cake part and eat it before you could leave the meeting room and go do something else.
>
> Rinse and repeat **one week later** because it's **Jean-Baptiste's birthday.**
>
> Rinse and repeat **one week later** because it's **Sandra's birthday.**

The routine gets in, and everyone does it because it must be done, put no heart in it and think about what work could be done instead, just like the point you raise.

If you feel that there are too many of these events, you could check with your colleagues and see how they feel about it. If there is a general consensus that there could be less of it, you could suggest to upper management to reduce the number of occurrences.

I'm not sure about the implication of reducing the amount of cultural related celebrations, but you could certainly suggest to celebrate the birthdays of the employees to once a month: Everyone that has its birthing during that month get celebrated, and you do this on the first Monday of the month, for instance.

Some places have a beer during the afternoon on Fridays, just to relax and encourage employees to interact with each other, not necessarily in relation with work. If there is this kind of practice at your place, you could move some celebrations done at that moment. ("We'll have a cake for Amanda's birthday this Friday, come celebrate *if you want*!")